# Javascript Arrays to create table

Tags: javascript, arrays, html-table

I am trying to create a table using the arrays for a program outline for school.  How do I make the second array (num) line up next the course title. Right now it is just stacking below them in the same column....

```
<script>

var titl = ["Oral Communication","Applications/Concepts","SQL Programming","HTML and Dreamweaver","Javascript","Flash","XML","Cascading Style Sheets","XSL","ASP.NET","PHP/MySQL","Windows Operating Systems","Digital Imaging with Photoshop","Web Development Internship"];
var num = ["ENG171","CIT110","CIT236","CMT111","CMT113","CMT115","CMT117","CMT125","CMT211-see note*","CMT215","CMT241","CIT268","VMA105","CMT299"];

document.write('<table>')
document.write('<tr><th>Web Development Concentration Courses</th></tr>');

for (var i = 0; i < titl.length; i++)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + titl[i] + '</td></tr>');
}

for (var j = 0; j < num.length; j++)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + num[j] + '</td></tr>');
}
document.write('</table>'); 

</script>
```

Comment: Do you mean having the elements in `titl` in column 1 and elements in `num` in column 2, side by side?

Comment: Yes Exactly! Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot split things when you are constructing HTML. Also, please do not use `document.write`, as it is dangerous.

Also, the main solution is to combine the loops. I am doing it by checking the lengths of the two arrays to be same:

```js
var titl = ["Oral Communication", "Applications/Concepts", "SQL Programming", "HTML and Dreamweaver", "Javascript", "Flash", "XML", "Cascading Style Sheets", "XSL", "ASP.NET", "PHP/MySQL", "Windows Operating Systems", "Digital Imaging with Photoshop", "Web Development Internship"];

var num = ["ENG171", "CIT110", "CIT236", "CMT111", "CMT113", "CMT115", "CMT117", "CMT125", "CMT211-see note*", "CMT215", "CMT241", "CIT268", "VMA105", "CMT299"];

var finalHTML = '<table>';
finalHTML += '<tr><th>Web Development Concentration Courses</th></tr>';

if (titl.length == num.length)
    for (var i = 0; i < titl.length; i++) {
      finalHTML += '<tr><td>' + titl[i] + '</td><td>' + num[i] + '</td></tr>';
    }

finalHTML += '</table>';

document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = finalHTML;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Also, giving the `<th>` a `colspan="2"` will give you better results:

```
finalHTML += '<tr><th colspan="2">Web Development Concentration Courses</th></tr>';
```

[image: preview]

Answer (score 0):

Combine the two loops

```
for (var i = 0, j= 0; i < titl.length || j < num.length; i++,j++)
{
    document.write('<tr><td>' + titl[i] + '</td> <td>' + num[i] + '</td></tr>');

}
```

Comment: You aren't incrementing, or even using, `j`.